# Unable to access Temp files while debugging winForms project in Visual Studios 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, clickonce, visual-studio-debugging, certificate

I have several programs that I have created in vb.net visual studios 2010. I have been working on these programs for months with no problems. Recently I started having an issue where I can no longer access my temp directory while debugging within VS. I can't use My.Settings anymore because these use those temp files. This is the error I get:

> Failed to save settings: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\PROGNAME\PROGNAME.exe_Url_gty0snnfox5ji5xgprklljwb0e0mthek\1.0.0.0\nl3u0fw2.tmp'. (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\PROGNAME\PROGNAME.exe_Url_gty0snnfox5ji5xgprklljwb0e0mthek\1.0.0.0\user.config)*

This file is there though.

I also get an error when trying to use my web services. I get this error:

> Access to the temp directory is denied.  Identity 'DOMAIN\Username' under which XmlSerializer is running does not have sufficient permission to access the temp directory.  CodeDom will use the user account the process is using to do the compilation, so if the user doesn�t have access to system temp directory, you will not be able to compile.  Use Path.GetTempPath() API to find out the temp directory location.*

I used the Path.GetTempPath() as the error says and I am trying to access: >"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\"

I have tried going to these folders and making sure that I have the security set to allow everyone complete control. I believe it is a problem with VS not my program because I get the same problem on all of my programs, some of which I haven't opened in months. I did a repair on VS.

I can't think of what might have changed to cause this to stop working all of a sudden. I traveled to a customers facility where I had to change some network settings, but everything should be set back as it was now. My temporary security certificate expired, but I created a new one and now the certificate I am using to sign these applications is in my trusted root on certificate manager and looks to be valid. I should also mention that this is a clickonce deployment and the deployement works fine on my computer and others, it is only while debugging that I have these issues.

I have been running this down for weeks and spent countless hours looking for a solution and have come to a  brick wall. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks ahead of time for your help and time! Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was coming from the fact that somehow one of the folders in the filepath to my user.config file got changed. Somehow a .vshost got thrown in on one of the folder names. I still have no idea how this happened and what caused this to happen, and I am not 100% sure that I have gotten to the real root of the problem, but for now, I am able to debug again. I changed the file name back to what it was supposed to be and the errors have stopped. Now lets just hope the file name doesn't get changed back again.